# Как изменить код с чтением данных с отладочной платы под свои задачи?

Tags: python, stm32, serial

Есть код, который получает данные с платы (плата отправляет числа 10 раз с интервалом в 1 секунду). Как написать функцию, которая бы выжидала полное получение данных с платы (т.е. все 10 тиков счетчика) и затем записывала их все в массив данных? Плата STM32F407Discovery, код для платы был скомпилирован в STM32CubeIDE

```
import serial
def open_ser():
port = 'com4'  # Серийный номер
baudrate = 115200  # Скорость передачи
try:
    global ser
    ser = serial.Serial(port,baudrate,timeout=0.5)
    if(ser.isOpen()==True):
        print("Последовательный порт успешно открыт")
except Exception as exc:
    print("Последовательный порт открыт ненормально",exc)

def read_msg():
try:
    print("Ожидание получения данных")
    while True:
        data = ser.readline(ser.in_waiting).decode('ASCII')
        if data != '':
            break
    print("Данные получены:",data)
except Exception as exc:
    print("Прочитать исключение",exc)

def close_ser():
    try:
        ser.close()
        if ser.isOpen():
            print("Последовательный порт не закрыт")
        else:
            print("Последовательный порт закрыт")
    except Exception as exc:
        print("Последовательный порт ненормально закрыт", exc)

open_ser()
read_msg()
close_ser()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Исправьте отступы в функциях open_ser() и read_msg)
2. Вызовите функцию read_msg() десять раз в цикле